# wcag 2.4.4 Link purpose (in context) resolution

Tags: wcag

The table has 10 no. of column and 10 no. of rows. each row have product id hyperlink. example p01, p02 however screen reader announces as p01 link, p02 link. does the link text should be more descriptive ?
Also another column with each row has show here hyperlink however screen reader announces as show here link. does the link text should be more descriptive ?
how to make the application accessible for screen reader user ?

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the "[understanding](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/link-purpose-in-context.html)" section for WCAG 2.4.4.  It says:

> [Context] can be achieved by putting the description of the link in the same sentence, paragraph, list item, **or table cell** as the link, or in the **table header cell** for a link in a data table, because these are directly associated with the link itself.

Note that a "table header cell" is a `<th>` element and it specifically says a header cell because when a screen reader user navigates to a table cell, the table header is read before the cell contents. Your example shows "view" for the column header, which isn't very descriptive to me so that's not really adding context for "show here". In fact, I'm not sure what "show here" means. It sounds like clicking on that link will suddenly show you a picture of the product within that cell.

If the context were in the cell itself, then the context would be read when the user navigates to that cell.

As far as whether "P0" is descriptive enough, if that's really the name of your product, then I guess so.

Comment: when user click on the product link , a new tab gets loaded but screen reader remains silent and when user click on show here link , another table gets loaded in the same page so what should be the expected result?

Comment: That's a separate question and should be posted as a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75651254/screen-reader-does-not-read-out-when-a-new-tab-or-a-table-is-loaded  new question has been posted. kindly provide the answer.